# Is the result of MethodBody.GetILAsByteArray Method being cached? If so, how to clear the cache?

Tags: c#, android, mono, unity-game-engine, il

As an android game developer, I am using the MethodBody.GetILAsByteArray method to get the IL codes to detect if a given method has been modified (injected) by the user using other app (e.g. Cheat Engine). For example,

```
class A
{
    public foo()
    {
        // do something here.
    }

    public static byte[] GetILByteCode() {
        return typeof(A).GetMethodInfo("foo").GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray();
    }
}
```

I can get the injected version of the function "foo" if I call the function A.GetILByteCode() after the function "foo" is being injected.

If I call A.GetILByteCode() first, and inject some code in "foo". When I call A.GetILByteCode() again, it will return the origin version of the function "foo" instead of the injected version.

It seems that the result of GetILAsByteArray() is cached.

So my question is, can we clear the cache of GetILAsByteArray(), and get the most updated IL code of the target method?

Answer (score 0):

Since reflection is very expensive. The .net runtime caches types pulled up by reflection, and in each one of these caches members called by reflection.

I believe you can try exhausting the type cache, as it only has a few members (I think it is 16 members). The member cache might be unlimited.

However, if they are using cheatengine, I don't think they are changing the IL but actually changing the actual jitted code. So I don't think there is much you can do here.

CLR jit compiles every method that gets called, I don't know if Mono offers an interpretation mode.

Comment: The part about CheatEngine is correct. Usually to fight against it you would store key information on a server and not locally.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. We did use System.Type.GetType for more than 100 classes, but no help to exhaust the ILAsByteArray cache. :(

Comment: FYI, we are using Unity3D to develop the game (i.e. using Mono), and it has been launched. We confirmed that some cheaters are using Cheat Engine like app to modify the game logic (not information) e.g. bypass some function call.

Comment: Sorry, this is admittedly from my reading of the .net RuntimeTypeCache it could be implemented differently in mono. I remember reading that they created the handles as basically a way to avoid the rigermoral of deep inflection. In .net 4 it seems that the handle just wraps the type so I think they might have switched how the cache is implemented. Also I got the number wrong. Sorry, ActivatorCache is 20 members. I can't find a number on the runtime type cache.